# (Timestamp: {timestamp(local)}) is not working in Enterprise Library 4.0

Tags: c#

I am using Enterprise Library 4.0. It's having a time difference issue in logging.
Application is saving the log in databse using UTC time. Then i changed the formatter in web.config to get the local time. Timestamp: {timestamp(local)}

But this is not worked for me.

Comment: This is a very old and retired release. Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx) info page. Try to upgrade to version 6.0.